# Table text-align style overrides align attribute

Tags: html, css, html-table

I got the following table, which should center my DIV:

```
<table width="100%" height="100%">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="middle">
      <div id="someCenteredDiv"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But the problem is that there is a global stylesheet which defines:

```
td {
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left; }
```

It seems like the stylesheet overrides the align and the valign attribute. And when I try to override the style with

```
text-align: center;
```

it simply doesn't change anything.

Comment: use an id or class.. they have more preference than normal tag based styles

Comment: The issue is with centering the div rather than the text align. While it's possible they have an issue with their text-align setting being overruled it wouldn't work anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A div is a block element so it can't be centred using text-align: center. You could set it to `display: inline-block;` or give it a fixed width then use `margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: Thanks, now it works. The strange thing is, that it worked for block elements with the align attribute only.

Answer (score 1):

If your div has fixed width you can use:

**margin: 0 auto;**

On your div, to center it. Text-align will work only with inline elements, so if your div is not set to 'display: inline' (or inline-block) it won't be centered.

Answer (score 0):

For over-riding a style you can use !important as follows

```
td
{
text-align: center !important;
}
```

And to center-align the div element you must use `margin:0 auto` along with some `width` assigned.

Comment: You are right. I misunderstood the question. I am going to edit my answer. Thanks for pointing.